# How to go through images in a file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm working on a c++ app with visual studio 2015 that requires going through a folder containing a number of images to be processed in a particular order.

I need to use two buttons (left and right) to navigate through the folder. Therefore, accessing the previous or next image is triggered by the user.

Can anyone introduce me to any tool or method to do that?

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: I'm kind of new to c++ so I don't know how to start. I don't know if I should use a Windows form for the buttons or just a loop while checking key states with GetKeyState().

Comment: Start by loading and showing a single image on screen. This requires picking a GUI framework (I would recommend Qt over Windows forms). Once you get going, adding the next/previous behavior will come naturally.